# Replace all values with first observation by group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

For each group, defined by 'id', I would like to select the value in the *first row* of columns 'x' and 'y', and replace all subsequent values with that first value.

Some data:

```
id    Visit   x        y
1      1      0        1
1      2      1        2
1      3      2        8
2      9      1       11
2      10     12      14
```

I want:

```
id    Visit   x        y
1      1      0        1
1      2      0        1  # <- x & y replaced with first values of 'id' 1 
1      3      0        1  # 
2      9      1        11  
2      10     1        11 # <- x & y replaced with first values of 'id' 2
```

I tried this:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  arrange(id, Visit) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(x, y, 
       .direction = 'down',)
```

However, that doesn't seem to be doing it. Can someone help?

Comment: `tidyr::fill` is meant to fill *missing values*, not fill down existing values. Namely, it works when you have `NA` present.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `first` with `across` on `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    arrange(id, Visit) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(across(c(x, y), first)) %>%
    ungroup
```

Answer (score 7):

A `base` alternative using `duplicated`:

```
df[, c("x", "y")] = df[(i = !duplicated(df$id)), c("x", "y")][cumsum(i), ]
#   id Visit x  y
# 1  1     1 0  1
# 2  1     2 0  1
# 3  1     3 0  1
# 4  2     9 1 11
# 5  2    10 1 11
```

---

Using a `data.table` rolling join to "fill down" the first value within each group (fast on larger data):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[ , c("x", "y") := df[!duplicated(id)][.SD, on = .(id, Visit), .(x, y), roll = Inf]]
df
#    id Visit x  y
# 1:  1     1 0  1
# 2:  1     2 0  1
# 3:  1     3 0  1
# 4:  2     9 1 11
# 5:  2    10 1 11
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you want a base-R version of @akrun's awesome answer:

```r
df[c("x","y")] <- lapply(df[c("x","y")], function(z) ave(z, df$id, FUN = function(y) y[1]))
df
#   id Visit x  y
# 1  1     1 0  1
# 2  1     2 0  1
# 3  1     3 0  1
# 4  2     9 1 11
# 5  2    10 1 11
```

(I purposefully avoided using `dplyr::first` or `data.table::first`, as that would defeat the point of using this base R version.)

Or a data.table variant:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, c("x","y") := lapply(.SD[,c("x","y")], first), by = .(id)]
```

As @Henrik just mentioned, it's (much!) better to use `.SDcols` here:

```r
df[, c("x","y") := lapply(.SD, first), by = .(id), .SDcols = c("x","y")]
```

Comment: Hi @r2evans! You should avoid the `.SD[...]`: for every iteration in `by` it calls `[.data.table` which has a large overhead. Instead use `df[, c("x","y") := lapply(.SD, first), .SDcols = c("x", "y"), by = id]` which is much faster on larger data. Cheers

Comment: Thanks @Henrik, I wasn't aware of the performance issue there. I'm familiar with `.SDcols` in general, and I can see with this data that it can make a 3x difference in performance. I haven't seen that as a note in `data.table` docs, is there a mention of it?

Comment: @Henrik, do you know if there has been any discussion on using the .`SDcols` names in the LHS without pre-defining a vector? For instance, `df[, (.SDcolnms) := lapply(.SD,...), .SDcols=c('x','y')]`. I know it can easily be handled with preassigning `nms <- c('x','y')` and using that in both places ... just curious. Thanks again.

Comment: I can't find an explicit advice _against_ `.SD[..]` in the docs. Rather described the other way around - how a "non-indexed" `.SD` is fast: `?datatable.optimize`: "The expression `DT[, lapply(.SD, fun), by=.]` gets optimised [...]. This improves performance tremendously" There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/613) "Optimize `.SD[i]` query..." with heaps of links where you perhaps can find something relevant.

Comment: Regarding the names, there is a popular feature request: [`names(.SD) := ...` should work](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/795). Stay tuned!

Comment: Nice discussion chain, bummer it's been discussed for years, nothing recent, and despite some agreement on `names(.SD):=` or `.SDcols:=`, no consensus has been reached. (Is your "stay tuned" sarcasm on the 7-year issue, or do you have insight?)

Comment: A relevant [note on not to use `.SD[...]` in FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#how-can-i-avoid-writing-a-really-long-j-expression-youve-said-that-i-should-use-the-column-names-but-ive-got-a-lot-of-columns)

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option

```
with(
  df,
  cbind(
    df[c("id", "Visit")],
    cbind(x, y)[ave(1:nrow(df), id, FUN = function(x) head(x, 1)), ]
  )
)
```

gives

```
  id Visit x  y
1  1     1 0  1
2  1     2 0  1
3  1     3 0  1
4  2     9 1 11
5  2    10 1 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr, `head()` can also be used

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(x = head(x, 1), y = head(x,1)) %>%
    ungroup
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option in base R is to use the split-apply-combine paradigm via `split()`, `lapply()`, and `do.call()` with `rbind()`:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2), Visit = c(1,2,3,9,10), x = c(0,1,2,1,12), y = c(1,2,8,11,14))

df <- do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(split(df, df$id), 
          function(z) {
                z$x <- z[1, "x"]
                z$y <- z[1, "y"]
                return(z)}))
```